# Why is boost::mpi::request.test() returning an invalid statistic

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, distributed-system

I have a memory problem in with boost-mpi exchanges.
The exchanges are asynchronous on the sending side and synchronous on the receiving side because of needs of the application and it has worked in basic mpi code before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::mpi::environment env;
  boost::mpi::communicator world;
  size_t irank=world.rank();
  if (irank == 0) {
    std::vector<int> V(100, 0);
    boost::mpi::request req = world.isend(1, 37, V);
    while(true) {
      boost::optional<boost::mpi::status> stat = req.test();
      if (stat) {
        if (stat->error() != 0) {
          std::cerr << "Rank 0: Non-zero error in stat\n";
          char error_string[10000];
          int length_of_error_string;
          MPI_Error_string(stat->error(), error_string, &length_of_error_string);
          fprintf(stderr, "err: %s\n", error_string);
          return 1;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    while(true) {
      boost::optional<boost::mpi::status> prob = world.iprobe();
      if (prob) {
        if (prob->tag() == 37) {
          std::vector<int> V;
          world.recv(prob->source(), prob->tag(), V);
          std::cerr << "Rank 1: Correct receiving of the vector\n";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The message is correctly received, but the error of **mpirun -np 2 ./CTYP_debug** is

```
Rank 0: Non-zero error in stat
Invalid error code (14263904) (error ring index 27 invalid)
Invalid error code (14263904) (error ring index 27 invalid)
err: Unknown error class, error stack:
(unknown)(): MPI_Info_create failed
Rank 1: Correct receiving of the vector
```

To me this shows some memory problem, but I cannot find what is wrong. DDT did not show any apparent error.

Comment: It may help if you actually specify which MPI implementation you are using. The problem with `boost::mpi` is that it does a lot behind the scenes and so may obscure the true source of the problem.

Comment: The bug happens with a variety of implementations: OpenMPI 4.0.5 on Macintosh, mpich 3.3 on Linux. As I understand, it is a race condition, so it may happen in some cases, but not in others.

Comment: It all works without those diagnostics here. GCC + openmpi + Boost MPI 1.74.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. (except the warnings about lack of highspeed NICs)

Comment: After recoding with the C-API and getting the same error, I understood the problem. The underlying function to **test()** is **MPI_Test**. As it turns out the error field is not set in the status field in that case. See e.g. https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears occurs with the **.test()** which depends on **MPI_Test**.
As it turns out, the error field of the **MPI_Status** struct is not set in the MPI_Test call. See https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html for details.